# list of line charts with a single calliper

Tags: mpandroidchart

I want to create a graph view as shown in the following image:

[image: Example Graph]

Multiple line charts has to be displayed in the `ListView` with a single line showing the selected value for particular x value will be displayed at the end of each chart.